# Airflow Broken DAG: no module named somepackage

Tags: airflow

I have added my own package to /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (which is in sys.path):

somepackage
  **init**.py
  helper.py

The following DAG is located in /usr/local/airflow/dags/dev

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
import somepackage.helper as nf
print(nf.__file__)
import numpy as np
print(np.sqrt(2))
import datetime as dt
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

stage = 'dev'

# An usual python method which can be executed:
def print_world():
    print('world')


# Meta informations for airflow:
default_args = {
    'owner': f'{stage}',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2020,2,13),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'queue': stage
}

# The definition and 'script' of the DAG:
with DAG(f'test_{stage}',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval=None) as dag:

    # Define the steps in the pipeline, see airflow docs for more operators:
    print_hello = BashOperator(task_id='print_hello', bash_command='echo "hello"')
    print_world = PythonOperator(task_id='print_world', python_callable=print_world)
    makefile = BashOperator(task_id='makefile', bash_command='touch /usr/local/airflow/dags/justToTest.txt')

# Pipeline: first do x then do y then do z ....
print_hello >> print_world >> makefile
```

I can see the file in the Web UI and all print statements in the log. However Airflow keeps saying in the Web UI that the module is not found in the read header.

Comment: **[1]** do you have a dockerized deployment? **[2]** are you using Python virtual environment of some-kind? **[3]** are you using executor other than `SequentialExecutor` or `LocalExecutor`? *in all likelihood, your custom module is not on `PYTHONPATH` of your `webserver` process*

Comment: [1]Yes it is puckel/docker-airflow and in the Dockerfile I have added my module to the site packages directory. [2] I am using CeleryExecutor. [3] If I print sys.path in a DAG, I can see in the logs that site-packages path is part of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fairly simple: The other services (worker,..) were not getting the right docker image. The package was missing there and only available in the webserver service.

Comment: so how did you pushed the dags to the worker?

Comment: I dont get this, can you explain further?

Comment: The code is executed on the worker and that container was missing the dependency

Comment: I think it just simply meant install the missing packages within your container, and not locally.